# “had already worked with…” vs "has already worked with…”

Tags: past-tense

Can someone correct my mistakes?

> Michael has been warned from the very moment he had entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper. He was warned because everyone else **had already worked** with Andy

or

> Michael has been warned from the very moment he had entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper. He was warned because everyone else **has already worked** with Andy

Are they corrects?
Whats the difference in meaning?

Comment: You first sentence ("Michael has been warned") is in the present tense. Is that what you intended? In a typical story (told in the past tense) you would start "Michael had been warned" and the 2nd sentence would also be in the past tense: "He was warned because everyone else had already worked with Andy."

Comment: I realize this is a 4-yr old question, but voting to close as unclear unless it can be edited to clarify whether the author wants to be telling this narration overall in the present tense.

Answer (score 1):

Are you describing a recent situation, or telling a story about something that happened in the past?

If you are talking about things that have happened very recently: *Michael has been warned from the moment he entered the factory that Andy is... He was warned because everyone has worked with Andy.*

In the past: *Michael had been warned from the moment he had entered the factory that Andy was... He was warned because everyone had worked with Andy.*

The past perfect is appropriate when we are telling a story set in the past and we mention something that had happened *before* that.

Comment: Could" entered" be changed into  "has entered "to imply that Michael is still working in this factory  (there is still a present effect )

Comment: @YvesLefol -  In the  case of the first one, I think that is implied anyway - _has been warned_ implies a present effect.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Good afternoon! Can one of the Past Perfects in "Michael had been warned from the moment he had entered the factory that Andy was..." be changed into a Past Indefinite? If it can, which one is it? (I would assume it to be: "Michael had been warned from the moment he entered the factory that Andy was...", to underline the fact that he had still been warned at the moment of the author's past, i.e. that he kept that in mind at that moment-the Past Perfect Inclusive).