# Present perfect tense for life's experience

Tags: tense, present-perfect

"I have been an officer before."

Here I want to say is my life's experience that I was an officer.

Is it correct?

Comment: You were an officer when you were a baby?

Comment: When I was 21 years old.

Comment: It depends on the context, but I might say "I used to be an officer."

Comment: Thank you very much@Daniel Rose man.

Comment: It depends how long you were an officer for.

Comment: Yes ,exactly 13years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to express such a thing.  I think we need more clarification on what you mean when you say, *It is your life's experience that you were an officer.*

To say that you have only ever been an officer, never something else, and are possibly still an officer.  You would say,

> I have always been an officer.

To say that you have experience being an officer at sometime in the past. You would say,

> I have been an officer before.

Comment: I have been an officer before. means at some other time before this one. in other words, I still am an officer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lambie

Comment: "I have [done something] before" usually means that you are doing it for the second time. You might say "I have been an officer before" if you left the armed forces some time ago and have now joined up again.

Comment: Thank you @Kate Bunting.

Comment: Hello @Kate Bunting,I would like to ask you this explanation" If recent: Michael has been warned from the moment he entered the factory that Andy is... He was warned because everyone has worked with Andy."I have never seen this usage.Could you please explain me why you use present simple, past simple because present perfect in the explanation.

Comment: I can't answer that here; it is part of [a different question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244189/can-someone-correct-my-mistakes-has-had-v-had/349999#349999) .

Comment: @Lambie - *I have been an officer before,* does not exclusively mean you are still an officer.  *Do you have any experience as an officer?  Yes, **I have been an officer before.***  The phrase means, at the most basic level, *I have at some point in the past been an officer.*  Period.  Without more context we're just guessing.

Comment: Thank you @EllieK

Comment: @EllieK Would you be so kind to elucidate one grammatical discrepancy to me? English learners have always been taught that the Present Perfect is not to be used with adverbs of past time sphere, such as "before". It must be the Past Indefinite. However, sometimes the Pr. Perf. can denote the recurrent actions in the time lapse which is leading up to the present. I.e. "I have been a police officer twice since I quit being a shoplifter".

Comment: And I think I could wrap my head around "I have been a police officer (at least) twice before (now I am that officer again or I might consider enrolling in the police again". Maybe it's a question of Britain (classical) and American English?

Comment: @Eugene - Excellent question.  For most situations the rule you observe is a rule I observe.  That being said, I had to consider my answer and I stand by it.  In AmE, *I was an officer*, is not the stand-alone answer to the question, *Do you have any experience as an officer?*  *I was an officer,* would only be used in answering the question if more information was to follow, *I was an officer at Officers Unlimited.*  The stand-alone answer to that type of question is, *I have been an officer before.*  It violates no idiomatic rules in that context.  It has a lot to with it being an **answer**

Comment: @EllieK Thank you! It was that "before" that had muddled me around first off.

Comment: And what would you say about this? "What were you at those times? I have been an officer from 1980 to 1990."

Comment: @Eugene - No.  I would not say that.  *What were you?* is answered with, *I was....*   *Do you have any experience [being something/as something]?* is answered with *I have been....*

Comment: @EllieK Maybe it's all about the chain of consecutive recurrent actions with "experience" and the like? "I have been an officer", i.e. I attended my service as an officer every day in an unspecified period of time leading up to the present? With "before" it looks like the question is being asked right at the recruiting facility where I have just come to enrol: "Do you have any experience as an officer?" - "Yes, I have been an officer before (it could have been both once or a good few of times before which is unclear, though) and right now I'm anticipating joining the ranks again".

Comment: I love all of your discussions because I understand clearer.Now I will not join Army again and it can't happen again.According as your discussions that I read ,now I understand to use just simple past such as I was an officer,I used to be an officer and I am no longer an officer.I accept the answers that all of you have discussed.@Lambie,@Kate bunting,@EllieK and @Eugene.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been an officer for 15 years.

I became an officer 15 years ago. I remain an officer today.

> I was an officer for 10 years until I quit and became a lion tamer.

I am no longer an officer. That was in the past.

> Have you ever eaten a raw oyster?
>
> -- Yes, I have eaten raw oysters before. If I were to eat a raw oyster today, it would not be for the first time. I am, in fact, an expert oyster eater.  Not really. I'm joking. I have only eaten a raw oyster once before. I do not intend to eat another.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation@TimR.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a reason why the fact of the speaker having past experience as an officer is particularly relevant to the *current* conversation and/or the speaker's current circumstances, he should just use Simple Past...

> ***I was an officer***

Personally, I don't think that "I want to say [it] is my life's experience that I was an officer" is good enough reason to use a pointlessly distracting and unnecessarily complex verb form. I remain convinced that far too many learners use Perfect verb forms far too often *and it shows*.

One obvious likely reason for using Present Perfect in OP's context is if the speaker wants to continue with something like *"...and I might consider serving **again***". In fact, that kind of connection is *so* likely I'd probably assume it even if the speaker never said or meant that. Which is precisely why using the "wrong" tense causes problems.

Comment: Thank you very much@FumbleFingers.