# Past perfect tense "emphasize"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tense

I understand that "he was warned from the moment he entered"is in the same timeline

"Michael was warned from the moment he entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper.He was warned because everyone had worked with Andy."

1.If I want to emphasize both "enter and warn"

"Michael had been warned from the moment he had entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper.He was warned because everyone had worked with Andy."

would it be wrong?

2.If I want to emphasize "warn"

"Michael had been warned from the moment he entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper.He was warned because everyone had worked with Andy."

Would it be wrong ?

3.In the time line of events If I think  "entered" is first later "was warned" , how also would it be? if I write "Michael was warned from the moment he had entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper. He was warned because everyone had worked with Andy."

Would it  be also wrong?

I am being confused past perfect.

Comment: "Michael was warned" is a story told in the past tense. "Michael had been warned" doesn't emphasise the verb, it sets it back to an earlier time than the main story. Compare "John came home at midnight on Saturday" with "John woke up late on Sunday morning because he _had come_ home at midnight the night before".

Comment: Hello sir, okay now I get the one point.Story told in the past tense I have to write "had been warned and had entered".But here I want to know is why both tenses have to use past perfect "had been warned and had entered". It is the because of "from the moment"same time line? If I use only "had been warned and he entered ",would it be wrong?@Kate Bunting

Comment: I have said several times that, in a story told in the past tense, you use the past perfect **to refer to something that happened earlier than the events of the story**.  You do **not** have to use the past perfect for every verb. "Michael had been warned from the moment he entered the factory..." is fine (if the main events of the story happen some time after he started work there). PS I'm female, so don't call me 'sir'!

Comment: If in the time line of events entered is first later was warned  
"Michael was warned from the moment he had entered the factory that Andy was a local version of a grim reaper.He was warned because everyone had worked with Andy.would it be wrong?@Kate Bunting.

Comment: No, that would be OK **if the story is set at the time Michael started work at the factory**. I have been trying to explain the difference ever since my answer to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244189/had-already-worked-with-vs-has-already-worked-with/349999#349999)! You could also use _from the moment he entered..._

Comment: Thanks for your patience@Kate Bunting